# Fatal allowed memory size exceeded when using class extend

Tags: php, class, methods, extend, public-method

When I use a lot of class extends, I get this error:

`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65488 bytes) in C:\Web\private\bootstrap.php on line 5` (I made sure this is actually the line for the code below. My original code said line 22.)

This is my code (massively abridged, but still creates the error. My original has `this->this` 6 levels deep!).

```
class test { // Root class.
    public $system;
    function __construct() {
        $this->system = new system();
    }
}
class system extends test { // System classes and methods.
    public function demo($string = 0){echo $string;}
}
$test = new test();
$test->system->demo("hello");
```

This should output a mere `hello` but unfortunately it throws the error instead. What is causing this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursion

When you instantiate `system`, you are extending `test` which is calling the `__construct()` method, which is in turn creating a new `system` object, which extends `test` and calls `__construct()`, etc, etc.

Why are you creating a new `system` object in your `test` class if `system` extends `test`?

Comment: That is a good point. My problem was that I want to have the extended bit (like `$test->this->accessDB()`) that can access the database, with the database connection opened and included in the first class, called `$test`. I need to keep the database connection and data from 'parent' classes without an extend. Can I do this?

Comment: Where are the database connections? In `test` or in `system`? And where do you want to use them - `test` or `system`?

Comment: Sorry, they are in `test` but used in `system`. They have to stay in `test` though because of the way the application is laid out.

Comment: `system` extends `test`, therefore by inheritance it will have all of the properties and methods that are available to `test`. If `test` has a method called `accessDB()` then just call `$this->accessDB()` from `system`.

Comment: Oh, but I mean if I remove every `extends test` from the class, will it still inherit?

Comment: No, but you don't need to remove `extends test` to make this work. You just need to remove `$this->system = new system();` from the `__construct` method in `test`, and use `system` in your code instead of `test`. Alternatively, you can remove `extends test` from your `system` object, and instead pass one when you create it: `new system($test);` which you can use inside of your system object. For more information you can read up on Composition vs Inheritance

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24477/discussion-between-mindcore-and-colin-morelli)

Answer (score 0):

You code is causing an infinite loop of recursion.

When you create a new Test, it creates a new System, which calls Test's constructor (since it is inheriting it), which creates a new System ... repeat.

If you removed the inhertience from system, then it will work fine.

```
class system { // System classes and methods.
    public function demo($string = 0){echo $string;}
}
```

Comment: Or if (s)he removes the call to instantiate a class that they already have a reference to in `$this` ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an infinite loop.

When you try to instantiate `new test()`.  Your constructor creates a new system object (which itself is a test object, you it would then instantiate another system object and on and on until you run out of memory.

If you don't need the system object to instantiate a new system object you should override the constructor (with an empty function even).